# Getting this error while running cucumber tests using gradle cucumber task

Tags: gradle, cucumber, cucumber-java

Getting the following specific error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must exist: /Users/poc/userTest/{projectdir}/Dapiurl=https:/myapiurl-signal/v1
```

When i am executing the following command from Intellij macos integrated terminal

```
./gradlew cucumber -Dapiurl=https://myapiurl-signal/v1
```

Can someone please help here? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Tried executing this command and expected that my cucumber script must execute

```
./gradlew cucumber -Dapiurl=https://myapiurl-signal/v1
```